# How to replace whitespace on both tomcat and websphere

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

Dev: Tomcat and Oracle JDK 1.6
Test: WebSphere and IBM JDK 1.6

The string ends in a no-break space (U+00A0/#160) when submitted to the web service.
In Tomcat, the solution below works, however in WebSphere, the no-break space comes through as a (U+00C2/#194).

```
public static String removeWhiteSpace(String inputString) {
    return inputString == null ? null : inputString.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+", "");
}
```

What would you have to do to make this work in both tomcat and WebSphere.

Comment: That's weird since U+00C2 is an `Â`. Maybe you're having codepage/characterset issues somewhere upstream.

Comment: Pretty sure it's something to do w/ the characterset, but can't test w/out a deployment.

Comment: So the problem is elsewhere. Not in the code shown. No way we can help with that.

Comment: The is a question about how websphere handles string encode vs how tomcat string encoding by default and how to account for it in both environments.

Comment: If you cant use WebSphere for dev, use WebSphere Liberty. It is as lightweight as Tomcat, but uses mostly same libraries as traditional WebSphere, and you will have less issues while transferring from dev to test.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we ended up going w/ was to replace both possible outputs:

`\\u00C2\\u00A0` replaces the No-Break space in our WebSphere environment.
`\\u00A0` replaces the No-Break space in our tomcat environment.
`\\s` replaces any normal whitespace characters.

**In the Java:**

```
inputString.replaceAll("(\\u00C2\\u00A0|\\u00A0|\\s)+", "")
```

**Downside:**

In Tomcat, it is possible to accidentally replace a `u00C2` character if it immediately precedes a no-break space. However, the risk was deemed acceptable.